# Center map on current location using osmdroid

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid

I've got a very basic Android app in Kotlin.

I'm trying to center the map on the current location of the device, but `myLocationOverlay.myLocation` is always `null`.

Am I doing something wrong? I've been furiously googling but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var map: MapView
    private lateinit var mapController: IMapController
    private lateinit var myLocationOverlay: MyLocationNewOverlay


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Load and set layout
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Create MapView
        map = findViewById(R.id.map)
        // Set tile source + display settings
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true)
        map.zoomController.setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER)

        // Create MapController and set starting location
        mapController = map.controller

        // Create location overlay
        myLocationOverlay = MyLocationNewOverlay(GpsMyLocationProvider(this), map)
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation()
        myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation()
        myLocationOverlay.isDrawAccuracyEnabled = true
        myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix{runOnUiThread {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.myLocation)
            mapController.setZoom(9.5)
        }}
        map.overlays.add(myLocationOverlay)

        // Set user agent
        Configuration.getInstance().userAgentValue = "RossMaps"

        println(myLocationOverlay.myLocation)
        println("Create done")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        map.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        map.onPause()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. I needed to request the permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION first. The following code works for me when added to the start of the `onCreate` function:

```
        // Request Location permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            println("Location Permission GRANTED")
        } else {
            println("Location Permission DENIED")
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                1
            )
        }
```

A pop-up appears the first time you run the app in an AVD emulator asking for location permissions.